# Unable to start netperf server

Tags: networking, 12.10, performance

I am working on Ubuntu 12.10 and I just installed netperf by `apt-get install netperf`. Then I tried to start netperf server by running `netserver` and I got `Unable to start netserver with 'IN(6)ADDR_ANY' port '12865' and family AF_UNSPEC`

Can anybody help me? I didn't find anything about it in netperf FAQ.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While netserver's behavior seems to be somewhat unusual on Ubuntu, I think that you may find the netserver service to be already running.
If you run a `ps -ef | grep netserver`, you may find the process already running and you should be able to perform netperf queries against it.

Upon installing netperf on my local machine, I was able to run netperf with several flags set and get results back.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to stop the netserver so you can start it with other options, `service netperf stop` should work, if memory serves.

And while you are running tests, do keep in mind there is more to the networked performance of a system than bulk transfer, so be certain to give the *_RR tests (especially TCP_RR) some attention.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. This problem exist because the default port number is already occupied by the system.

```
sudo netserver -p 50000
```

**(here you can use other free port number available in your system)**

This solves my Problem.

Answer (score 0):

None of this worked for me. In the end I had to specify the actual ip to listen like this.

```
netserver -4 -L 192.168.0.1
```